# Modal Delete Button Not Working asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am making a page that stores clients. Clients can have domains and contacts and jobs.
Each contact/domain/job has edit/delete functionality.

I am using MVC 4 ASP.NET c# 
each time you wish to edit/delete it launches a modal form.
The delete view for contact and domain is exactly the same except for the fields that it displays.  The domain delete function does not fire anything when it is in partial view. But it succeeds when it is navigated to in the url as a regular view.  the contact delete works fine in the partial view.

```
@model STClient.Models.Domain

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DeleteDomain";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteDomain", "Client", FormMethod.Post)) {
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h2>Are you sure you want to delete?</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="display-label">
                <h3>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.server.ID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name):
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="display-label">
                <h5>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Registrar):
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Registrar)
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div class="display-label">
                <h5>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PrimaryDNS):
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PrimaryDNS)
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div class ="display-label">
                <h5>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SecondaryDNS):
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SecondaryDNS)
                </h5>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn" href="">Cancel</a>
        <input class="btn btn-danger" type ="submit" value="Delete" />
    </div>
}
```

this is on the details page where the delete link is for the domain.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteDomain-modal"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".deleteDomain").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Client/DeleteDomain",
                type: "GET",
                data: {id: $(this).attr('id')},
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(e)
                {
                    $("#deleteDomain-modal").html(e);
                }
            });
            $("#deleteDomain-modal").modal();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

And finally in the Client Controller

```
    public ActionResult DeleteDomain(int id)
    {
        Domain domain = db.Domains.Find(id);
        if (domain == null)
        {
            HttpNotFound();
        }
        return PartialView(domain);
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("DeleteDomain")]
    public ActionResult DeleteDomainConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Domain domain = db.Domains.Find(id);
        Server server = db.Servers.Find(id);
        db.Domains.Remove(domain);
        db.SaveChanges();
        db.Servers.Remove(server);
        db.SaveChanges();
        LogDeleteDomain(domain, server);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: have you tried using Fiddler to make sure that it's routing to the correct URL?  also, does Contact (the one that works) call the same Controller and Action (Client/DeleteDomain)?

Comment: I tried using fiddler but its not catching anything because the delete button is not firing anything.  the contact delete function calls client/deletecontact

Comment: Please share your partial view DeleteDomain

Comment: that is the first piece of code that I posted and in the last piece of code it says return partialview()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I had a similar problem. The reason was that parameter value was send as string and not as integer. I had to cast the value. So in your script code you may try to change the line:

```
data: {id: $(this).attr('id')},
```

to:

```
data: {id: parseInt($(this).attr('id'))},
```

That solved my problem.

Comment: that just made it not fire the modal at all.  The id of the domain is getting to the modal fine its just the delete button not firing the click event. only in the modal.  if you map to the url directly it works fine

Comment: @Gina have you tried to use "DeleteDomainConfirmed" instead of "DeleteDomain" in the form, maybe also without the ActionName("DeleteDomain") attribute?

Comment: @Gina I would run the site in Firefox with firebug activated. After pressing the button the dialog, I would take a look at the network tab, where the form was sent.

Comment: I tried youre advice but nothing happens again because it is not firing at all in the modal view